# Происхождение слова "бобыль"

Tags: этимология

В детстве я думала, что слово "бобыль" пишется через А — "бАбыль", от слова "баба"))) А в самом деле, от какого слова оно происходит?

Answer (score 3):

По Фасмеру:

> бобыль бобы́ль "безземельный крестьянин, поденщик" (между прочим, см. у Котошихина 98). По мнению Микколы (Berühr. 89 и сл.), заимств. из сканд., ср. др.-исл. bū́ "крестьянское хозяйство", bóli, landbóli "издольщик, наемный работник", *b́uabóli "издольщик", др.-шв. boaböle, boabyle; см. также Бернекер 1, 65 и критику фонетической стороны этимологии у Тернквист (223 и сл.). Затем Миккола (ÄВ 50 и сл.) отказался от этой этимологии якобы потому, что это слово известно в русск. лишь с XVI в. Впоследствии он считал его экспрессивным словом и сравнивал со шв. bobbe, англ. bob "увалень", англ. baby или лит. bumbilas 1 "батрак", 2. "лентяй", лтш. bumbulis "клубень". Все это чрезвычайно гадательно. Следует обратить внимание также на рум. bobîlcă "вид танца", bobîlnic "настурция", не объясненное у Тиктина 1, 202.

С исторической точки зрения все версии никуда не годятся, так как бобыли как социальный клас появились первоначально в Москве в самом конце XV века. Так обозначали слуг по договору, работавших на господина и/или плативших оброк. Причём положение у них было даже хуже, чем у кабальнозависимых.

Такое ощущение, что тут прямая связь  с бобами. Бобы считались самой простой, распространенной  и дешевой пищей, в засушенном виде могли храниться долго и не портиться. И если в доме из еды не осталось ничего, кроме бобов, то дела действительно плохи. Остаться на бобах значит остаться почти безо всего. По такой же схеме работает выражение "остаться без штанов". Аналогичные выражения на основе "бобов" есть и в других языках. Бобыль тогда - это тот, кто на бобах, "бесштановский".

Comment: Экспрессивная-то версия почему никуда не годится?

Вполне логичная. Не говорю "правильная", но вполне правдоподобная.  

Что касается бобов, то, имхо, за уши притянуто. Сначала появились сами бобыли и слово, только потом их связали с бедностью, нищенством.  

Изначально это была просто некая группа (не класс, конечно), не платившая обычные налоги (потом и с них стали брать т.н. бобыльшину).

Comment: Народная этимология, короче.

Answer (score 0):

На мой вкус, внятного ответа тут не было. 
Думаю, что правильнее всего будет сказать, что слово темное, без внятной этимологии.
А из догадок правдоподобнее всего, конечно, версия об экспрессивном образовании. По крайней мере она ничему не противоречит.

Про бобы и бодыли даже говорить не хочу всерьез.

Answer (score 0):

"Бо" - потому что (Словарь древняго славянскаго языка составленный по Остромирову Евангелию Ф. Миклошичу, А. Х. Востокову, Я. И. Бередникову и И. С. Кочетову. Издание А. С. Суворина С.-Петербургъ 1899). "Быль" - существующий. Все вместе -человек, который существует, потому что существует. Образовано аналогично словам "прибыль", "убыль", "пробыль". Другой вариант - от слова "боб". (Бобышка - скругленный короткий брусочек, бобина - женского рода; бобыль - мужского рода. Он "круглый", как и сирота).

Comment: А что такое "Бо"? И на каком это языке?

Comment: "Бо" - в словаре древнеславянского языка имеет значение "ибо", "потому что", "для того, что".

Comment: На словарь ссылочкой не побалуете? Хотя, если Вы поклонник Фоменко, то лучше не надо. А какая связь у "бо" и "были"?

Answer (score 0):

По мнению В.Татищева это слово — татарское, означающее — неимущий, из крестьян, не имевших пашни; многие из них занимались промыслами и торговали. До 1625 года они не платили гос. податей, но после были сравнены с прочими крестьянами.

Об этом написано в «Опыте повествования о древностях русских» Г.Успенского.

Answer (score -1):

Можно связать со словом  бодыль - веточка.беда. ( -Б-Д- )

Comment: Нельзя связать.